# Mounting Hard Disk Window Server 2008 without Server Manager

Tags: windows, window, mount, hard-drive

Mounting Hard Disk Window Server 2008 without Server Manager

My server manager have an error

```
mmc could not create the snap-in. CLSID: FX:{18ea3f92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb} when opening server manager.
```

This happen after i did a server reboot, i want to mount my another hard disk which normally i mount it as Drive D , using server manager, but due to server manage have issue. I cant mount it.

I did .NEt framework 4 reinstall and also did rename of machine.config as machine.config_old as what some sites suggested but to no avail.

How can i mount my drive d or get the issue fixed..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the hard disk in Ubuntu and look at the log?